# Attempting to assemble and run nasm on mac OSX

Tags: macos, assembly, nasm

So for awhile I have been using the Irvine library to kind of dip my toes into assembly (masm) language. Moving up in the world I want to get off the training wheels and let go of the Irvine library and jump into the pool with nasm on mac OSX. The problem here is I cannot even get terminal to open up the simple nasm hello world file. 
The scene looks like this:

1. simple nasm hello world file written and saved to desktop
2. terminal is opened up and

   `nasm -f macho64 -o hello.o hello.asm`  (I have also tried .nasm and macho and macho32)

is inserted into the terminal.

3. A fatal error occurs which does not allow me to continue the learning process.

   `nasm: fatal: unable to open input file 'hello.asm'`

Any help would be greatly appreciated because I have looked up a solution but cannot find any "helpful" advice. (Quotation marks because the advice is just not specifically helpful to my situation, or does not work to solve the problem.)

Comment: If the file is on the desktop and not in the current directory then you need to supply full path. Or change to the appropriate directory first.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem here was very simple and I hate myself a little for not realizing my mistake. The answer to this was very simple: to allow permissions with sudo.

```
`sudo nasm -f macho32 -o hello.o hello.asm`
```

You live and you learn I suppose.

Comment: Something is not right if you need sudo to access  a file on the desktop.

Comment: What do you mean? How would I fix that or check whats wrong with it?

Comment: Use `ls -l hello.asm` to check the permissions and ownership.  Were you running your editor as `root`?

Comment: Well I had to in order to assemble the file. Before that I dont think I was.

Comment: When I opened the terminal no but I did not know that was necessary until I tried it

Comment: @Liam Elevated privileges (i.e. using sudo) should never be necessary to assemble a file.  Something else is wrong and using `sudo` merely masks the issue.